# Tablayout is ruined after changing compile sdk version from 23 to 24

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I already had an app with a perfectly working tablayout.But after changing the compile sdk version from 23 to 24 a small gap appears in the second tab.

It should look like this.

[image: first tab is correct]

But it looks like this,with the black gap.

[image: error tab]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this

Both these tabs use the same layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/dashboard" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_text_color"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

dashboard.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progbar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/txt"
      android:text="These are your active court Proceedings"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#D9DCDE"
      android:scrollbars="vertical">
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope my question is clear.Please give me a solution for this.
Thanks.

Comment: try `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`....

Comment: where should I change it?

Comment: in xml: for  `widget.DrawerLayout`...

Comment: I changed it in Drawerlayout and CoordinatorLayout..and it Worked...

Comment: if u post this as answer I will accept it...Thanks.

Comment: okay i am posting it as an answer..

Comment: .widget.CoordinatorLayout also needs android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows)

**android:fitsSystemWindows**

> Boolean internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system
>   windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this
>   view to leave space for the system windows. Will only take effect if
>   this view is in a non-embedded activity.

so set `*android:fitsSystemWindows = "false"` for `DrawerLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```